# Can you use ANY SQLITE3 database in iOS, or is there a special format you should match?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

Specifically, it would be nice to be able to use a database I already have that Rails 3 generated and just stick it straight into iOS.  Would that be possible?

I know that Rails expects a specific format to the database, and you'd have to massage the data to get an arbitrary database to work with it.  Would it be the same for IOS?  Or would it be completely useless?

I'm fine with relations (like has_many) not working right out of the box, as long as I could somehow just access the ids and the like.

Comment: jbh's answer notwithstanding, you might want to check the [version compatibility](http://www.sqlite.org/formatchng.html), but if you're dealing with relatively current versions on both platforms, you're probably in good shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite database is stable cross-platform, [see here](http://www.sqlite.org/different.html)

Then, once your schema is defined, you can use with any programming language you desire.

Comment: So unlike Rails, iOS doesn't do any automatic database to object conversions?  So I would still have to roll my own "turn each row in this table into an object code", but I would have complete control?

Comment: @Jenny I don't specially know iOS programming, but maybe there are [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) that can be used in Objective-C. If you search complete control, use SQLite API directly, and you should have what you desire